# Modificar valor de COOKIE por un FORM

Tags: php

Tengo una consulta que no estoy pudiendo resolver o no se:
Tengo una página que guarda, en una Cookie, el mail del usuario al ingresar.
En otra página, figuran los datos de acceso del usuario, incluyendo el mail.
Ahora, si el usuario modifica su mail, necesito que esa Cookie tome el valor del nuevo mail que el usuario ha modificado...
Estoy trabajando con PHP.
Gracias!

Creación de cookies al momento del login del usuario:

```
<?php

session_start();

include("conexion.php");

$dni=$_POST['0dni'];
$mail=$_POST['0mail'];  

if (empty($dni)||empty($mail)) {
    header("location:../index.php?error=FALTAN%20DATOS");
} else {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE dni='$dni' and mail='$mail'";
    $consulta=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql);
    $existe=mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta);

    if ($existe==1) {
        $_SESSION['dni'] = "$dni";
        setcookie("user_dni", $row[2],"","/");
        setcookie("user_apellido", $row[3],"","/");
        setcookie("user_mail", $row[5],"","/");         
        header("location:sec.php");
    } else {            
        header("location:index.php?login=false");           
    }
}?
```

Formulario que envía el nuevo mail a la BD y FORM donde se carga el nuevo mail:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['dni'])) {?>


<html lang="es">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/imta.css">
</head>
<body>
    <content>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <b>Ingresar su nuevo e-mail:</b>                    
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm txt" id="txt_new_mail_1" name="usuario_email_1">
                    </div>    
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">                        
                        <b>Reingresar su nuevo e-mail:</b>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm txt" id="txt_new_mail_2" name="usuario_email_2">
                    </div> 
                </div>  
                <div class="row align-items-center">            
                    <div class="col text-right" id="btn_cambiarmail">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn_aplicar_mail" name="aplicar_mail"><b> APLICAR</b></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn_cancelar_mail" name="cancelar_mail"><b> CANCELAR</b></button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </form>                
        </div>
    </content>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body> </HTML>
```

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['aplicar_mail'])) {
        include("conexion.php");
        $usuariodni=$_COOKIE['user_dni'];
        $usuario_new_mail01=$_POST['usuario_email_1'];
        $usuario_new_mail02=$_POST['usuario_email_2'];            
        if ($usuario_new_mail01==$usuario_new_mail02) {
            $sql="UPDATE usuarios SET mail='$usuario_new_mail02' WHERE dni='$usuariodni'";                
            if (mysqli_query($acceso,$sql)) {                    
                //ACÁ ES DONDE QUIERO QUE LA COOKIE DEL MAIL SE ACTUALICE CON EL INGRESADO POR EL USUARIO
                echo "MAIL MODIFICADO";
            } else {
                echo "ERROR EN BD";
            }
        } else {
            echo "LOS CORREOS NO COINCIDEN";
        }
    } else {
        //header("location:datos_acceso.php?error=00");
    }
} else {
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

?>

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi El problema es que no se cómo hacer, para que al usuario cambiar el mail en el formulario (con la sesión ya iniciada obviamente), la cookie tome ese nuevo valor. Debe de ser una tontez... pero no lo logro... Me funciona todo, la BD se actualiza, pero cómo hago para darle a esa cookie un valor nuevo.

Comment: Y como creas la cookie?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @gbianchi Edité la pregunta y agregué el código de creación de cookies. Cuando las utilizo en otras páginas funcionan.  El usuario al ingresar, puede modificar su e-mail después, pero no se cómo cargo ese nuevo mail en la cookie inicial del mail.

Comment: Y cual es el problema de mandar una nueva cookie? lo probaste?

Comment: @gbianchi Sí y no me funciona... pero creo encontrar el error... tengo armado el formulario HTML y el código PHP de modificación de mail en la misma página... esto está muy mal no? Ahora edito la pregunta.

Comment: He solucionado el problema (al menos así lo pude hacer): el código PHP lo hice en otro archivo y no en el mismo donde figura el FORM.